# Nested query sql hospital

Tags: sql, oracle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93ber.jpg)

```sql
select Fname,Lname,salary,ssn
from Employee
where joptype='nurse' AND salary <= ALL (select salary
from Employee E,Nurses N
where E.Ssn=N.Ssn AND E.joptype='nurse' AND N.shift='morning')
```

I want to return a list of nurses name who works at morning and their salary is less than all nurses, or the opposite. I've tried both morning and night, also I've tried greater than all nurses. I think the problem is in the second where it seems like he ignores the shift condition.

Comment: Please show both sample input data and the expected result as tables in your question, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I did add pictures of all tables and the code with the output

Comment: Your question does not contain any pictures. Pictures are not the correct choice, better use tables with text. Please read the article linked in my last comment and also this one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: "nurses with salary less than all nurses" - are you sure you should get any?

Comment: I don’t understand do u mean use ANY Instead of ALL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` to find the morning shifts and, from Oracle 12, you can use `ORDER BY salary ASC FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` to find the matching employees with the lowest salary:

```sql
SELECT Fname,
       Lname,
       salary,
       ssn
FROM   Employee e
WHERE  jobtype='nurse'
AND    EXISTS( SELECT 1
               FROM   Nurses N
               WHERE  E.Ssn=N.Ssn
               AND    N.shift='morning' )
ORDER BY salary ASC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

or, if you want to check all nurses and find the minimum salary and then filter on morning shifts:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT Fname,
         Lname,
         salary,
         ssn
  FROM   Employee
  WHERE  jobtype='nurse'
  ORDER BY salary ASC
  FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
) e
WHERE  EXISTS( SELECT 1
               FROM   Nurses N
               WHERE  E.Ssn=N.Ssn
               AND    N.shift='morning' )
```

If you want to use a `JOIN`, rather than `EXISTS`, then you can use:

```sql
SELECT e.Fname,
       e.Lname,
       e.salary,
       e.ssn
FROM   (
         SELECT Fname,
                Lname,
                salary,
                ssn
         FROM   Employee
         WHERE  jobtype='nurse'
         ORDER BY salary ASC
         FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
       ) e
       INNER JOIN Nurses N
       ON E.Ssn=N.Ssn
WHERE  N.shift='morning'
```

(However, if there are multiple entries in `Nurses` for an `Employee` then you will get duplicates using a `JOIN` that you would not get using `EXISTS`)

Or for your code, you appear to have the filter for shifts in the wrong place:

```sql
SELECT e.Fname,
       e.Lname,
       e.salary,
       e.ssn
FROM   Employee e
       INNER JOIN Nurses n
       ON (e.Ssn = n.Ssn)
WHERE  e.jobtype='nurse'
AND    n.shift='morning'
AND    e.salary <= ALL ( SELECT salary
                         FROM   Employee
                         WHERE  jobtype='nurse' );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ru9iSfUL)

Comment: How can u use nasted in FROM?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood it; what you said:

> their salary is less than all nurses

probably means *their average salary*, so I used it in a subquery.

```
select e.fname, e.lname, e.salary, e.ssn
from employee e join nurse n on e.ssn = n.ssn
where e.joptype = 'nurse'
  and n.shift = 'morning'
  and salary < (select avg(salary)         --> average salary of all nurses
                from employee
                where joptype = 'nurse'
               );
```

(Just a remark: is it really jo**p**type? Is it not a jo**b**?)

Comment: In the OP's question `shift` is a column on the `Nurses` table and not the `Employee` table. Also, the OP does not want the average, they want the minimum.

Comment: Right; thank you! Though, how do you know they want the minimum?

Comment: My query question is to return nurses name and salary, but only nurses who works at night and their salary is greater the all nurses for example ,, I just need to use nasted query

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "their salary is greater than all nurses"? All nurses (if you SUM their salaries) certainly have larger salary than nurses who work only in the morning (because they represent a **subset** of all nurses). I'm afraid I don't understand what you said. If possible, post (by editing the question) sample data which would illustrate the problem and desired result based on that sample data.

Comment: I meant like if i have 3 nurses with (15k,12k,12k) salary I want the output be : the name of nurses with 12k bc 12k is the minimum number of salary

Comment: Ill try to post the pics

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try it like here:

```sql
select 
    Fname,  Lname,  salary,  ssn
from 
    Employee
where 
    joptype='nurse' AND 
    salary <=   (   Select  MIN(salary)
                    From    Employee E 
                    Inner join      Nurses N ON(E.Ssn=N.Ssn)
                    Where   E.joptype = 'nurse' AND 
                            N.shift = 'morning'
                )
```

... this will give you the list of nurses with salary less than or equal to the minimum salary among morning nurses..